# Detecting Angular Velocity in a React-Native mobile application

Tags: android, ios, react-native, physics, expo

I'm hoping to make a feature in a mobile application which detects how fast the user is spinning their phone and which direction. I believe this is angular velocity, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

For what it's worth, I'm experimenting with this idea using react-native (create-react-native-app) with the help of Expo dev tools, and the Expo accelerometer API. 
https://docs.expo.io/versions/v15.0.0/sdk/accelerometer.html

My question is perhaps more fundamental though. 
Can I reliably detect the speed at which the phone is rotating, and which direction? And would any code solution that I write provide consistent values across different mobile devices, or vary wildly?

Then, if it is a plausible feat, how would I determine such a value? Would I compare value from millisecond to millisecond, and if so, which values?

Thanks for helping me get my head around this.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm still not certain what the correct term is, I've managed to attain the value that I'm looking for by making use of the gyroscope API and monitoring the 'Z-value'. Here is my working example. (Needs to be run with [expo](http://import%20React%20from%20'react';%20import%20Expo,%20%7B%20%20%20Gyroscope,%20%7D%20from%20'expo';%20%20import%20%7B%20StyleSheet,%20Text,%20TouchableOpacity,%20View%20%7D%20from%20'react-native';%20%20export%20default%20class%20Test%20extends%20React.Component%20%7B%20%20%20constructor(props)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20super(props);%20%20%20%20%20this.state%20=%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20gyroscopeData:%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20x:%200,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20y:%200,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20z:%200%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20componentDidMount()%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20this._toggle();%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20componentWillUnmount()%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20this._unsubscribe();%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20_toggle%20=%20()%20=%3E%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20if%20(this._subscription)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._unsubscribe();%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._subscribe();%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20_slow%20=%20()%20=%3E%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20Gyroscope.setUpdateInterval(1000);%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20_fast%20=%20()%20=%3E%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20Gyroscope.setUpdateInterval(16);%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20_subscribe%20=%20()%20=%3E%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20this._subscription%20=%20Gyroscope.addListener((result)%20=%3E%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.setState(%7BgyroscopeData:%20result%7D);%20%20%20%20%20%7D);%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20_unsubscribe%20=%20()%20=%3E%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20this._subscription%20&&%20this._subscription.remove();%20%20%20%20%20this._subscription%20=%20null;%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20render()%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20let%20%7B%20x,%20y,%20z%20%7D%20=%20this.state.gyroscopeData;%20%20%20%20%20return%20(%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CView%20style=%7Bstyles.sensor%7D%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B/*%3CText%20style=%7B%7BfontSize:%2050%7D%7D%3E%20x:%20%7Bround(x)%7D%3C/Text%3E*/%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B/*%3CText%20style=%7B%7BfontSize:%2050%7D%7D%3E%20y:%20%7Bround(y)%7D%3C/Text%3E*/%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CText%20style=%7B%7BfontSize:%2050%7D%7D%3E%20z:%20%7Bz%7D%3C/Text%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B/*%3CView%20style=%7Bstyles.buttonContainer%7D%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CTouchableOpacity%20onPress=%7Bthis._toggle%7D%20style=%7Bstyles.button%7D%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CText%3EToggle%3C/Text%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/TouchableOpacity%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CTouchableOpacity%20onPress=%7Bthis._slow%7D%20style=%7B[styles.button,%20styles.middleButton]%7D%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CText%3ESlow%3C/Text%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/TouchableOpacity%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CTouchableOpacity%20onPress=%7Bthis._fast%7D%20style=%7Bstyles.button%7D%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CText%3EFast%3C/Text%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/TouchableOpacity%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/View%3E*/%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/View%3E%20%20%20%20%20);%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%7D%20function%20round(n)%20%7B%20%20%20if%20(!n)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20return%200;%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20return%20Math.floor(n%20*%20100)%20/%20100;%20%7D%20%20const%20styles%20=%20StyleSheet.create(%7B%20%20%20container:%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20flex:%201%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20buttonContainer:%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20flexDirection:%20'row',%20%20%20%20%20alignItems:%20'stretch',%20%20%20%20%20marginTop:%2015,%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20button:%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20flex:%201,%20%20%20%20%20justifyContent:%20'center',%20%20%20%20%20alignItems:%20'center',%20%20%20%20%20backgroundColor:%20'#eee',%20%20%20%20%20padding:%2010,%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20middleButton:%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20borderLeftWidth:%201,%20%20%20%20%20borderRightWidth:%201,%20%20%20%20%20borderColor:%20'#ccc',%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20sensor:%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20marginTop:%2015,%20%20%20%20%20paddingHorizontal:%2010,%20%20%20%7D,%20%7D);))

```
import React from 'react';
import Expo, {
  Gyroscope,
} from 'expo';

import { Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';

export default class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      gyroscopeData: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        z: 0
      },
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this._toggle();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._unsubscribe();
  }

  _toggle = () => {
    if (this._subscription) {
      this._unsubscribe();
    } else {
      this._subscribe();
    }
  }
  _slow = () => {
    Gyroscope.setUpdateInterval(1000);
  }

  _fast = () => {
    Gyroscope.setUpdateInterval(16);
  }
  _subscribe = () => {
    this._subscription = Gyroscope.addListener((result) => {
      this.setState({gyroscopeData: result});
    });
  }

  _unsubscribe = () => {
    this._subscription && this._subscription.remove();
    this._subscription = null;
  }
  render() {
    let { x, y, z } = this.state.gyroscopeData;
    return (
      <View>
        {/*<Text> x: {round(x)}</Text>*/}
        {/*<Text> y: {round(y)}</Text>*/}
        <Text> z: {z}</Text>

        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._toggle}>
            <Text>Toggle</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._slow}>
            <Text>Slow</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._fast}>
            <Text>Fast</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );  
  }
}
function round(n) {
  if (!n) {
    return 0;
  }

  return Math.floor(n * 100) / 100;
}
```